# Bash Jobs : how can I output job process information along with errors?

Tags: bash, error-handling, stdout, jobs

I'm using a bash script to import some data into a MySQL database. I'm parallelising the loads using jobs in...

```
for i in  *.sql; do
    {    
      echo "importing $i"
      mysql --defaults-extra-file=my.cnf < $i
      echo "$i load complete 
      
      } &
    
done
```

If one of the jobs errors, I see the error in stdout, but nothing to identify which of the jobs caused it. Is there a way to add the job process information to the error output so I which which one it was?

Comment: If you are seeing importing .....sql and then an error messages, you know it is the sql file from the importing message?

Comment: @AndrewPoodle : I would redirect the output of a job to a file and incorporate the file ID into the filename. Since you are running your compound command in the background, it is a bad idea anyway to just let the stdout slip out.

Comment: may be done with sed command `| sed -e "s/^/$i:/"`

Comment: or `2>&1 | sed -e "s/^/$i:/"`, to add stderr to pipe (added after closing brace)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/):

```
parallel --progress --tag 'mysql --defaults-extra-file=my.cnf < {}' ::: *.sql > import.log
```

This will run the `mysql --defaults-extra-file=my.cnf`  as many times as there are `.sql` files in the current directory, in parallel. You can decide on the maximum number of parallel processes with the `--jobs` option.

The `--tag` option prefixes each output line with the file being processed. The output is redirected to a file for further reference, and the `--bar` options shows a progress bar for a visual feedback.